# xcrun xcodebuild ** EXPORT FAILED ** after installing Xcode9

Tags: ios-provisioning, xcode9, xcrun

After installing Xcode9, `xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive` started to `** EXPORT FAILED **`.

> xcodebuild[8520:2065474] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed:
>   IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fd93ba747d0: Error
>   Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating
>   signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating
>   signing assets failed.,
>   IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
>       "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 \"\"MyApp_Today.appex\" requires a provisioning profile with the App
>   Groups feature.

The error `requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature.` is repeated multiple times.

The provisions are present for each target in the project, but for some reason it's no longer enough. What is this "App Groups feature" and how do I make it work with `xcrun xcodebuild`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can see your App Groups settings on the Apple Developer console. https://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a "solution".
The error message is misleading, since it has nothing to do with 'groups'.

Xcode 9, and its tools have changed! 
Before Xcode 9, the `ExportOptions.plist` **did not** require specification of provisions, it was automatically retrieved from the given target/scheme.

BUT, since Xcode 9, it's required that `ExportOptions.plist` specify all the provisions for the given target/scheme.

You can read more here: https://blog.bitrise.io/new-export-options-plist-in-xcode-9

Comment: Hi thedp, in xcode 7 I was using following code for building  archive xcodebuild  clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO  -scheme helloworld clean archive -archivePath build/helloworld and to exporte ipa I was using  xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath "build/helloworld.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/myipa.ipa" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO  But now in xcode 9 none of the above is working in ipa creation using command line. do  you have any idea. I have gone through the blog but it didn't helped me.

Comment: @RajinderChandel Sorry, that's all I know on the matter

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Developer Portal Go to Your App ID and see if the App groups are turned ON or not. If they are not then Turn them ON by clicking Edit and the tick the checkbox next to App Groups
2. In Xcode Select you Target > Capabilities > App Groups > Turn it ON
3. Sign application with a provisioning profile for your application that has app groups entitlement.

If you don not want App groups just turn it off from App Capabilities...